# Live report of clover not being generated

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, clover

I wanted to get live coverage for the applications being tested but the live recording file of clover is not getting updated .I have to shut dwon my tomcat server forcefully.I am facing issues in shutting it down normally.This may be a reason for clover live recording not being updated.But how to go about in this scenario.Is there any flush policy that might be useful and how to mention it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is too borad. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to *.liverec* file. If so it doesn't contain any live recording of anything. It is a merely file indicator for Clover that, test execution is in place and Clover is still gathering coverage. If you kill the JVM, Clover might not have a chance to remove it. Clover checks for existence of that file while it generate the reports.

Clover with default flush policy dumps all coverage data during graceful JVM stop. If you're forcing JVM Clover runs in forcefully then Clover will never dump the data to hard drive. You can change default behaviour of Clover by using the [flush policy](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Using+a+Flush+Policy)